# Is the limit of the sequence $a_{n+1}=a+ba_n$ $L=\frac{a}{1-b}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Looking to find the limit when n tends to infinitive

```
0<a<1 and 0<b<1
```

$a_n=a+b(a+b(a+b(a+b...$

by trying term by term I got that the recurrent formula is

$a_{n+1}=a+ba_n$

I have tried the following:
If $a_n$ has a limit, this will be the same as $a_{n+1}$. Lets suppose this limit is L. 
Then we would have this equation:

$L=a+bL$ $\rightarrow$ $L=\frac{a}{1-b}$

I guess I have assumed the sequence converge, maybe this is an error...
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use induction to show that $a_n=a+ab+\cdots+ab^{n-1}+b^{n}a_1$ for every $n$. Now use the fact that $b^{n} \to 0$ and use the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: Thank you that means I am wrong maybe if was such a beautiful answer! Ill try your idea now

Comment: @yomismito Your idea is correct, but you need more proves

Comment: ok thats true , before applying my idea I need to make sure the sequence converge

Comment: @kavi your answer is correct I have just checked it but as I have no reputation I cant upvote your answer yet

Comment: @yomismito No problem. Thanks for approving the answer.

Comment: I had the same thoughts, but unless I have misunderstood the series, doesn’t the last term not include $a$? Not that it changes the answer.

Comment: @Certainlynotadog There was a typo. The last term was supposed to be $b^{n}a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

You've shown that if a finite limit exists it's $\frac{a}{1-b}$, Subtracting this from the sum of the first $n$ terms, you can prove by induction the resulting error term is proportional to $b^n$, so $\to0$ as required because you've assumed $0<b<1$. Of course, if $|b|\ge1$ the terms don't shrink to $0$, so the sum cannot converge to any finite limit.

Comment: Nice different approach thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that a finite limit exists call this limit $L$ and you find from the recursion equation that $L = a + b L$ which gives you $L=\frac{a}{1-b}$.

Comment: thats exactly what I did , thank you

Comment: Sorry for carelessly repeating your argument. I might add the $a$ can be any number, no restriction needed.

Comment: I agree as it is not inside any power of n, no problem, thank you for your help

Comment: You could also normalize the recursion dividing it by $a \ne 0$ and continue the solution with $c_n = \frac{a_n}{a}$. The only non trivial parameter left is then $b$.